How to install npm react
I want to  install npx react-app@latest ./ --typescript --tailwind --eslint on my laptop but I am having this problem: npm error: you're behind proxy or have bad network connection
I tried installing npm offline but didn't work.

Do you mean npm init react-app …?

Create your project's folder
Open the POWERSHELL
Change the path to your project's folder
Then execute: npx create-react-app@latest --typescript --tailwind --eslint 
Or execute:
npx create-react-app ./
Then open your project in your IDE and execute:
npm install typescript @latest
npm install tailwind @latest
npm install eslint @latest

I think that might help
Also do you need help in create react app it self?
npx create-vite@latest --template typescript-react-tailwind-vite ./

